# Is there a way to center a div without a specified width or height?

Tags: javascript, html, css, overlay

I have the following HTML

```
<div class="modal_overlay">
    <div class="modal_window">
        Content
    </div>
</div>
```

and the following CSS

```
div.modal_overlay {
    display: none;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    background-color: rgba(150, 150, 150, 0.75);
}
div.modal_overlay .modal_window {
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: white;
}
```

The `modal_window` is populated with arbitrary content from an AJAX call.  Since I do not know the required width and height of the content, how can I make the `modal_window` take up the minimum required space and center it both vertically and horizontally on the screen?  I am looking for a solution that is compatible with most modern browsers where I do not have to specify a height or width in any child (recursively) of `modal_overlay` (including any elements in the AJAX content).  Is this even possible without using JavaScript?  If I must use JavaScript, what is one of the better ways of accomplishing it?

EDIT:  I also want to avoid changing the display types of either of the elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
div.modal_overlay .modal_window {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: white;
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

Comment: Brilliant!  It seems to work for all of the current AJAX calls.  I figured the solution was very simple.  This is probably a duplicate question in that case.  I understand that I need to use other transforms like 'moz-' and 'webkit-', but this nailed it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `display:flex` with `align-items: center;` and `justify-content: center;`. And working in all modern browser.

```
div.modal_overlay {
    align-items: center;
    background-color: rgba(150, 150, 150, 0.75);
    display: flex;
    height: 100%;
    justify-content: center;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zptqkvc2/)**

Comment: I didn't mention it in the original question at the time, but I wanted to avoid changing the display type.

Comment: @CzechErface Then `position:absolute` is only the option.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `min-width`, `max-width`, and position it absolutely in center.

```css
div.modal_overlay {
/* display: none; */
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
position: fixed;
left: 0;
top: 0;
background-color: rgba(150, 150, 150, 0.75);
}
div.modal_overlay .modal_window {
padding: 10px;
background-color: white;
max-width: 800px;
min-width: 300px;
min-height: 200px;
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
top: 50% ;
-webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
-moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
-ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="modal_overlay">
<div class="modal_window">
    Content
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't want to specify widths or heights, including minimums or maximums, but your solution would probably work without them.

Answer (score 0):

This is the simple way to center the div widhout specified height and width:

```
.center_div {
  position: fixed;
  display: block;
  z-index:999;
  right:40%;
  left:40%;
  bottom:40%;
  top:40%;
  background-color: rgba(150, 150, 150, 0.75);
}
```

You increase or descrease the width by increasing/decreasing the percent.